# "pressing a button" on a web page using a "GET" with java

Tags: java, http, gwt, get

I am trying to retrieve some text data from a specific web page.
In order to get the data, one needs to push a button on the page and then the text is presented in a new window.
I have inspected the code for the button and it seems like it invokes some `js` script that runs some calculations and then presents the output in the new window.

I would like to write a "GET" request that will fetch me the data automatically.
Is it possible? If so, what will be the fastest way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

[Here](http://rucsoundings.noaa.gov/gwt/?data_source=Op40&latest=latest&start_year=2016&start_month_name=Dec&start_mday=12&start_hour=9&start_min=0&n_hrs=1.0&fcst_len=shortest&airport=&gwt=Interactive%20plot&hydrometeors=false&start=latest) is the address of the webpage.

The text data is being presented when pressing the `Get text` button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't.
The text is generated by js on the fly.
You can open the page in a headless browser (i.e. phantomjs) and retrive it by

`jQuery('#SkewTPlot button:nth-child(2)').click()`

and then

`jQuery(".dialogMiddle textarea").eq(0).val()`

If you don't want to do it from your program you can setup a service 'proxy' which will scrape it occasionally or by request...